# Как преобразовать смайлик в "dec код" на php

Tags: php

Искал и ничего не нашёл, да и что именно искать не знаю.

Вот сайт, где есть нужная мне  функция, http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=
мне нужно такая же функция в php или javascript коде (а лучше на обоих языках), чтобы получать dec code как на этом сайте.

Comment: Как преобразовать 1 смайлик в код понятно, но как несколько их преобразовать в код я не понял. У них разная длина , да и вообще чёт не выходит разбить текст из 2 смайликов и засунуть в этот обработчик , который дал ilyaplot.

Киньте идею, что мне нужно сделать, но лучше напишите обработчик .-.
Который из строки со смайлами выводит код, например из "↘" нужно получить `"&#8600;&#127479;&#127482;&#128565;"`
Ps. в строке будет больше 100 смайлов.

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример разбора нескольких символов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$smiles = "↘";

function mb_ord($char, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    if ($encoding === 'UCS-4BE') {
        list(, $ord) = (strlen($char) === 4) ? @unpack('N', $char) : @unpack('n', $char);
        return $ord;
    } else {
        return mb_ord(mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', $encoding), 'UCS-4BE');
    }
}

for ($pos = 0; $pos < mb_strlen($smiles); $pos++) {
    $smile = mb_substr($smiles, $pos, 1, 'UTF-8');
    echo  $smile . ' => ' . mb_ord($smile) .PHP_EOL;
}


↘  =>  8600
  =>  127479
  =>  127482
  =>  128565
```

Взято отсюда [How to convert unicode charaters to unicode decimal entities php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657233/how-to-convert-unicode-charaters-to-unicode-decimal-entities-php)

Comment: Отлично , всё работает и как надо.Правда выполняется чаще чем нужно и выводит пустой результат, с ' if(empty($smile)) exit; ' перед выводом всё становиться ещё лучше, СПАСИБО!